# Pass auth cookie to WebView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm building a WebView based app.
Authenticating occurs **inside** the app **without using webview**. I'm making a request to server and getting a **session token from auth cookie**. 
When user passes authentication page the app pushes him to the main page.
There are some buttons that leads to the WebView. 
The problem is that I need to pass my auth cookie to the WebView.

However when WebView appears it i**mmediately redirects me** to web app authentication page instead of catalog page.
But I need catalog page.

I used [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin to pass cookies:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:skin_technology/core/session_data/repo/session_data_service.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class CatalogWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  CatalogWebView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  static const url = 'https://clubskt.ru/client/catalog';

  Future<String?> _getToken() async {
    final token = (await SessionDataService.sessionData)?.token;
    if (token == null) return null;
    return token;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: FutureBuilder<String?>(
          future: _getToken(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final token = snapshot.data;
              if (token == null) return Container();

              return WebView(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                initialUrl: url,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialCookies: const [
                  WebViewCookie(
                    name: 'auth',
                    value:
                        'eyJhbGciOzI1NiJ9.eyJzd...',
                    domain: 'https://clubskt.ru',
                  ),
                ],
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              );
            }
            return Container();
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

I also tried to pass cookie **throw the headers** in the same plugin:

```
return WebView(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  controller.loadUrl(url, headers: {
                    'Cookie': 'auth=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzd...'
                  });
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              );
            }
```

but the result is the same.

I opened **developer tools** in order to test request. Status code is 304.
[image]
But when I'm trying to reproduce the same request in **postman**, I get a status code 200. I'm passing a valid token throw auth_cookie.
[image]
Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution!

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:skin_technology/core/session_data/repo/session_data_service.dart';
import 'package:webview_cookie_manager/webview_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  WebViewScreen({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  final String url;
  WebViewController? webController;

  final cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();

  Future<String?> _getToken() async {
    final token = (await SessionDataService.sessionData)?.token;
    if (token == null) return null;
    return token;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            SafeArea(
              bottom: false,
              child: FutureBuilder<String?>(
                  future: _getToken(),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final token = snapshot.data;
                      if (token == null) return Container();

                      return WebView(
                        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        initialUrl: url,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          cookieManager.setCookies([
                            Cookie('auth', token)
                              ..domain = 'clubskt.ru'
                              ..httpOnly = false,
                          ]);
                          webController = controller;
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is it not easy doing it it with [flutter_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but would be way easier with the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin).

Here's an example

```
class Web extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> cookie;

  Web(this.cookie);

  @override
  _WebState createState() => _WebState();
}

class _WebState extends State<Web> {
  final webPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((event) async {
      final cookies = await webPlugin.getCookies();
    });
    webPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((event) async {
      if (mounted) {
        final cookies = await webPlugin.getCookies();
        switch (event.type) {
          case WebViewState.shouldStart:
            {
              print(event.type);
            }
            break;
          case WebViewState.abortLoad:
            {
              print(event.type);
            }
            break;
          case WebViewState.startLoad:
            {
              print(event.type);
            }
            break;
          case WebViewState.finishLoad:
            {
              print(event.type);
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<WebViewViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModelBuilder: () => WebViewViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, _) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: WebviewScaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: apex,
              actions: [IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.replay, color: Colors.white, size: 28,), onPressed: () => webPlugin.reload()),],
            ),
            clearCookies: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            headers: this.widget.cookie,
            url: "your url",
            withJavascript: true,
            withLocalStorage: true,
            withZoom: false,
            supportMultipleWindows: true,
            allowFileURLs: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    webPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem remains even with flutter_web_view_plugin. 
I've tried this: 

`WebviewScaffold(
                url: url,
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                headers: {'Cookie': 'auth=$token'},
                withJavascript: true,
                withLocalStorage: true,
                withZoom: false,
                supportMultipleWindows: true,
                allowFileURLs: true,
              );`

Comment: Share your code